# Calendar List view Android

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I want to develop a Calendar Listview. I tried using Calendar View.

```
 <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    />
```

But this scrolls horizontally. I did not find any attribute to scroll it vertically. How can I achieve vertical scrolling effect?

Update : I also want to set different background for different dates as in  the attachment.

[image]

Comment: For that check [this](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) and [this](https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview)

Comment: a similar question was posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822403/android-calenderview-change-scroll-direction-to-vertical) a while back, which doesn't have an answer. Why not try some library instead which could help you achieve that effect?

Comment: I had referred [link](https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview) but it doesn't display previous dates. It displays from the current day. @Nisarg

Comment: @madhuri H R let me check and try different attributes

Comment: @madhuri H R With [this](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) you can display previous dates

Answer (score 0):

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/970
check this lib it might be help...